# Can't connect to OpenVPN with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've not been able to connect to OpenVPN recently. Network Manager tells me that I'm connected, however if I check my IP address or do an online 'dns leak test' I find that I am not. I've tried with different VPNs with the same result. I've tried these VPNs on other computers and they work fine there. I've previously been able to connect via OpenVPN using Ubuntu before. I've also tried numerous different settings re. TUN/TAP/IPv4/IPv6 etc etc.

I've done the 'route' command with these results (while supposedly connected to VPN), but I can't really understand the results:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         193.180.119.129 128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tap0
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
no.rdns.ukserve gateway         255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.8.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       193.180.119.129 128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tap0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
193.180.119.2   gateway         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp3s0
193.180.119.128 *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 tap0
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions